# Is it better to use Http Requests and create a Notification or use Push Notifications?

Tags: android, http, notifications, push

Is it better to use HTTP Requests and create a Notification or use Push Notifications ? Just asking if there is a downfall to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Push NOtification - its actually Push + Notification.
I meen first you catch Push intent, and than you show Notification(by yourself).
If you want to implement HTTP + Notification, you will need to implement some kind of an web socket connection(on serverside and clientside) ofcourse if you want to have message about event when it actually occurs on server, not after you asking if something happend every n seconds, which will affect battery and network traffic. So generally it more easy and straight to use Push Notifications(GCM)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if u use GCM(Google cloud messaging) that is push notifications